# Removing hover features and auto loading from site

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to remove all hover features and auto loading from my site so I commented out all the code that is related to the :hover feature in my site but there is still hovering available.

I'm also trying to remove all the available auto load features like the loader transform and animations. I did but I still see both hovering and some animations.

Is there something that I could be missing?

Like this hover and transform features below I removed them

```
.cateogory ul li a:hover:before {
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.category-2 {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: From where did you remove all the :hover features? I am not able to understand your question

Comment: from my css pages

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your css file by editing your question?

Comment: @AtheeshThirumalairajan could you ptal at the css snippets

Answer (score 0):

In your code it looks like there is a typo

**cateogory**

```css
.category ul li a:hover:before {
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.category-2 {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

If that does not solve You may create another class and copy all inside and change its classname with javascript

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
.category ul li a:hover:before {
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.category-nohover ul li a:hover:before {
 
}


.category-2 {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: so I can remove the hover by creating a new class with an identical name and adding -nohover to it?